# Two links don't display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I typed 2 links in my header component but these links don't display. It's weird because everything seems ok with it. These 2 links are in ul list.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #563F7A">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ürün Listesi</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ürün İşlemleri</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ürün Çıkışı</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav
```

Comment: I thought it too. But I'm sure they are not displaying. I have tried to change the background color but i didn't see the links.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is with your containing `div`:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

The `collapse` class will hide your `div` as it adds the style `display: none` (if `.show` is not added), you need to remove this to see your links:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #563F7A">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ürün Listesi</a>
  <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ürün İşlemleri</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ürün Çıkışı</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```